# HMM - which are possible hidden states and observational states in this scenario?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have read about HMMs including an [weather example](https://www.google.co.zw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=HMM+weather+example) and how to apply them on [credit card fraud detection](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=HMM+for+credit+card+detection&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=). Now I want to apply HMMs to detect credit card fraud on an ATM transaction. I am confused as to which are **hidden states and observations** in my scenario.

**The situation is as follows:** A card holder is performing withdrawal transaction on an ATM, Now I want to use HMMs  to tell whether the transaction is fraudulent or not. I am considering features like:

1. Withdrawal amount.
2. Time to input PIN.
3. Location of ATM

I have tried to model it as follows: Hidden states on transaction as :Suspicious and Non-Suspicious. The observation as : withdrawal amount, time to input PIN and Location ***but its not making sense to me***.

**Question:**

Which can be my hidden states and observations?

Comment: It may be that your labeling is messing up your thinking about the problem.  Your hidden states should be labeled (something like) "Fraudulent" and "Non-fraudulent".  The probability dist'ns of the features are different for fraudulent and non-fraudulent transactions.  Suspicious and Non-suspicious are labels that are appropriate after the classifier has assigned a probability of Fraudulent to a particular transaction; for example, "Suspicious = P(fraudulent) > 0.1".   But really, I'm not seeing how there's any Markov process involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it make sense ? I am not sure if your question is about how to model Markov dependencies.

If your concern is about how to model the all 3 observation together, you can stack 3 observations in to a vector. Then this is your observation vector (like in a Kalaman filter). You can assume given the hidden states those three observations are independent. (If you cannot make that assumption still you can model it, but with complex observation probability distribution.)

If $Z^T = [Z_1,Z_2,Z_3]$ is your observation vector and $X$ is the hidden states, you can write the observation probability as, 
$P(Z\mid X) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^3P_i(Z_i\mid X)$.